# Remove all instances of {} interior to argument to a command

Tags: lyx, braces, catcodes, arguments, tensor

Is it possible to remove all instances of {} which are passed as parts of an argument to a command?

I would like to use the Tensor package with LyX.  The problem is that LyX always puts subscripts before superscripts.  The Tensor package has a command, `\indices`, which takes arguments like `^a_{bc}^{de}_f` and spaces them correctly.  In order to force LyX to accept these arguments in the right order, it is necessary to insert `{}` in the appropriate places: `^{a}{}_{bc}{}^{de}{}_f`.  Unfortunately, the Tensor package does not like this.  I would like to create an intermediate command which removes the extra `{}`s before passing the modified argument to `\indices`.  I know these are special characters with special catcodes.  I am not really sure where to begin with this.

(I know about the Tensind package.  I would rather use Tensor if I can get this functioning.)

Okay.  Here is a short example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{tensor}

\newcommand{\newindices}[1]{\indices{#1}} % would like to rewrite to remove every instance of {} from argument

\begin{document}%

\[
L\newindices{^{\mu}_{\nu}} %works
%L\newindices{^{\mu}{}_{\nu}} %does not work
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working (or non-working) example? If you can do this with `.tex`, you may get more help as people won't need familiarity with LyX.

Comment: @cfr I don't think anything I could post at the moment that would be useful.  I could post a working example using Tensor and show the error I get when inserting the {}s, but I can't really see what that would prove.  And the LyX end of things is really immaterial: I only mentioned that because everyone always wants to know why you want do something.  If I can get this to work in TeX/LaTeX, then I will have no problem getting the LyX end to work.

Comment: do you have to use `{}` it would be easier to remove say `|`  if `^{a}|_{bc}|^{de}` was OK

Comment: It's not about proving anything. It's about making it easier for people to help you. If you provided code, I might copy-paste it to play with. I have to be much more motivated by a question if I have to start creating a document from scratch, especially if I've got to begin by reading the documentation of packages I don't use.

Comment: "I could post a working example using Tensor and show the error I get when inserting the {}s, " That would be very useful

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, probably not.  That was something that someone suggested on the LyX site because it evidently works with Tensind.  Another delimiter may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loops through the argument dropping `{}` but taking care not to expand any macros it finds in the exponents.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{tensor}

\newcommand{\newindices}[1]{%
  \expanded{\noexpand\xindices{\zapempty#1\relax}}}
% would like to rewrite to remove every instance of {} from argument
\def\zapempty#1{%
\ifx\relax#1\space
\else
\ifx$#1$\else
\ifx^#1^\else
\ifx_#1_\else
\unexpanded{{#1}}%
\fi
\fi
\fi
\expandafter\zapempty
\fi}

\def\xindices#1{%
%\def\q{#1}\show\q% debugging
\indices{#1}}
\begin{document}%

\[
L\newindices{^{\mu}_{\nu}} %works
L\newindices{^{\mu}{}_{\nu}} %does not work
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you once again, David.  It worked like a charm, right out of the box!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `\def\macro#1#` in order to scan the parameter to the first `{` and then we can test, if the `{...}` includes something or nothing.

The following macro removes all occurrences of `{}` from its parameter:

```
\def\newindices#1{\expandafter\indices\expandafter{\expanded{\newindicesA#1{\end}}}}
\def\newindicesA#1#{#1\newindicesB}
\def\newindicesB#1{%
   \ifx\end#1\empty \else 
      \ifx\relax#1\relax \else {#1}\fi 
      \expandafter\newindicesA
   \fi
}

\newindices{^{\mu}{}_{\nu}} % runs \indices{^{\mu}_{\nu}}
```